# Replace elements of a multidimensional numpy array according to a rule

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, replace

Let's say we have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[ 5,  9],[14, 23],[26,  4],[ 5, 26]])
```

I want to replace each element with its number of occurrences,

```
 unique0, counts0= np.unique(arr.flatten(), return_counts=True)
 print (unique0, counts0)
```

> (array([ 4,  5,  9, 14, 23, 26]), array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]))

so 4 should be replaced by 1, 5 by 2, etc to get:

> [[ 2,  1],[1, 1],[2,  1],[ 2, 2]]

Is there any way to achieve this in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative solution since @Divakar's answer does not work in version <1.9:

```
 In [1]: import numpy as np

 In [2]: arr = np.array([[ 5,  9],[14, 23],[26,  4],[ 5, 26]])

 In [3]: np.bincount(arr.flatten())[arr]
 Out[3]: 
 array([[2, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2]])
```

To test for speed (with 10000 random integers):

```
def replace_unique(arr):
    _, idx, counts0 = np.unique(arr,return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)
    return counts0[idx].reshape(arr.shape)

def replace_bincount(arr):
    return np.bincount(arr.flatten())[arr]

arr = np.random.random_integers(30,size=[10000,2])


%timeit -n 1000 replace_bincount(arr)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 68.3 µs per loop
%timeit -n 1000 replace_unique(arr)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 922 µs per loop
```

so `bincount` method is ~14 times faster than `unique` method.

Comment: Lovely alternative one!

Comment: Also, you can use `.ravel()` instead of `.flatten()` thus avoid making a copy and a bit of performance boost that way.

Answer (score 3):

Use the other optional argument `return_inverse` with [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to tag all elements based on their uniqueness and then map those with the counts to give us our desired output, like so -

```
_, idx, counts0 = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)
out = counts0[idx].reshape(arr.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [100]: arr
Out[100]: 
array([[ 5,  9],
       [14, 23],
       [26,  4],
       [ 5, 26]])

In [101]: _, idx, counts0 = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True,return_inverse=True)

In [102]: counts0[idx].reshape(arr.shape)
Out[102]: 
array([[2, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```